# UUID and MACAddress for Bluetooth BLE

Tags: android, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I must confess I am a newbie when it comes to BLE 4.0, and I want to understand what comprises a unique identifier for a BLE peripheral. Generally, for all WiFi communications, MAC is treated as the unique ID for the device. I have following questions:

- What is UUID used for? Should different BLE peripherals have different UUID?
- What is unique ID for a BLE peripheral device, as identifiable by some other central BLE device? Say for example, how do location finding apps on Android detect a peripheral BLE device?
- Can one get Unique ID of a BLE peripheral simply by scanning (i.e, without connection)?
- Is any manual intervention needed to connect to a BLE peripheral? I've read that there is no need for manual opt in to read the data that peripheral transmits

Hope some of you could help.

Answer (score 9):

BLE devices have unique 6 byte Bluetooth addresses just like regular Bluetooth.  This uniquely identifies the device.  However, BLE can also use "random" addresses which follow a specific format so you can tell when you have a random addresses as opposed to a regular public address.

- In the BLE vernacular, "UUID" refers to the identification codes to identify the data types found in the Generic Attribute Protocol (GATT)
- Not sure I understand this question...  There's the Bluetooth address, but again, BLE devices can use random addresses.
- Well, when you do a scan for advertising packets you receive packets that contain the Bluetooth addresses.  Those addresses are what you use to connect to a specific device.
- You have to manually make connections to devices when you want to "connect".  However, advertising packets can contain data which you can receive passively without any sort of connection.  iBeacon's use the connectionless advertising packet information and so no connections are made.

Comment: I am reading documentation of BLE, and it says we need to connect to get the services and characteristics of that service. So does this connect require manual intervention, as in a pop-in on Android/iPhone app that asks for user permission? Or does this happen seemlessly without user knowing about it?

Comment: ah..  I have no idea how the iPhone or Android implements it.  But getting the characteristics requires 2-way communication traffic and thus some sort of connection.

Comment: Depending on the number, some of the service UUIDs can be listed in an advertising packet, so no two-way traffic is required to discover those, however a longer list does need to be actively querried.  Mobile operating systems seem to draw a line between "connecting" and "pairing" in that the first is typically allowed without user confirmation but the second usually requires it.