# How to identify an android device uniquely using its Bluetooth LE MAC address?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I uniquely identify each android device using its Bluetooth LE Mac address?

Does this MAC address changes on reboot?

How can I get my own device's Bluetooth LE MAC address?

Any suggestion on this will be great help for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311295/7066583) answers your questions pretty well.

I haven't tried this myself but it looks like you can access the MAC address with BluetoothDevice.getAddress() ([Android API reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress())).

In case you are working with iOS too, you cannot access a BLE device's MAC address; see [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8442) on Apple's Developer forum.

If you control the firmware of the device you are connecting to, you could name each device uniquely or put a unique identifier in the advertisement/scan response data. If you don't control the firmware of the device you are connecting to, it's possible that the manufacturer has done something like this.

Hope this helps!